# select array by any element exactly matched to specified value

Tags: json, jq

Anyone know to how to implement this?

I have an array which has a nested array, say tagNames, I want to select all item which tagNames contains "auto-test" exactly, not "auto-test2".

```
{
  "servers":[
      {"id":1, "tagNames": ["auto-test",  "xxx"]},
      {"id":2, "tagNames": ["auto-test2", "xxxx"]}
  ]
}
```

So far, I am using

```
echo '{"servers":[{"id":1,"tagNames":["auto-test","xxx"]},{"id":2,"tagNames":["auto-test2","xxxx"]}]}' |\
jq  '[ .servers[] | select(.tagNames | contains(["auto-test"])) ]'
```

I got two records, but I just want the first one.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tagNames": [
      "auto-test",
      "xxx"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tagNames": [
      "auto-test2",
      "xxxx"
    ]
  }
]
```

So I want this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tagNames": [
      "auto-test",
      "xxx"
    ]
  }
]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `contains/1` as it will not work the way you might expect it, particularly if you're dealing with strings. It will recursively check if all parts are contained. So not only will it check if the string is contained in the array, but if the string is also a substring.

You'll want to write out your conditions checking any and all tags against your criteria.

```
[.servers[] | select(any(.tagNames[]; . == "auto-test") and all(.tagNames[]; . != "auto-test2"))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the most easy-to-understand method. I end up with `jq  '[ .servers[] | select(any(.tagNames[]; . == "auto-test")) ]'`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `index/1`, e.g.

```
.servers[]
| select( .tagNames | index("auto-test"))
```

This produces:

```
{"id":1,"tagNames":["auto-test","xxx"]}
```

If you want that wrapped in an array, you could (for example) wrap the filter above in square brackets.

Comment: thank you for your amazing answer! I do not understand why this works. the `index` returns the first position of occurrence, so it maybe a number start from 0, while 0 should be converted to false, it is supposed to not work, but why it works now?

Comment: I also found that the `index` operator has an advantage that it can even handle null array (`tagNames` = null).

Comment: index/1 either returns an offset (i.e. 0-based index), or null if the item (or sequence) is not present.

Comment: thank you for answer. Got it. Though this is the most simple answer, sorry , due to it is a bit obscure, I finally gave the accepted answer to Jeff Mercado, jq '[ .servers[] | select(any(.tagNames[]; . == "auto-test")) ]'

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the idiom: first(select(_)):

```
jq '.servers[] | first(select(.tagNames[]=="auto-test"))' file
```

If the `first` is omitted, then the same item in the `servers` array might be emitted more than once.